# How to Get Rid of Padding in Material UI Container Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a hero banner using the material-ui framework.

So far what I have looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there is annoying left and right padding. I cannot seem to get rid of it.

My Hero component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    heroContent: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6),
    },
    heroButtons: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
    },
}))

const Hero = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()

    return <Container className={classes.heroContent}></Container>
}

export default Hero
```

Can someone please explain how I can get rid of the padding on the left and right, and achieve full width?

I tried setting the paddings in my styles as you can see,  but that has no effect. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: even after removing the padding, you will not get the full wdth container. as max width also applied there, you need to remove this property too

Comment: Thanks. I just added maxWidth={false} to my container, but it has not helped. Am I missing something? Also would there be any way to get rid of the 24px padding idiomatically?

Comment: i hpe you have access to your css, I am not sure that what this maxWidth={false} would do here, go in your css and write this,
.MuiContainer-root {max-width: 100% !important; padding: 0 !important;}

Comment: @finite_diffidence Though the `disableGutters` prop (as in my answer) takes care of this more easily, the approach in you `heroContent` CSS class works fine for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/container-disablegutters-forked-y9st6?file=/demo.js.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `disableGutters` prop removes the padding.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";

export default function SimpleContainer() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container disableGutters maxWidth={false}>
        <Typography
          component="div"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#cfe8fc", height: "100vh" }}
        />
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Container disableGutters]

Related documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/container/#props

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the issue perfectly!

Comment: I want this disableGutters functionality only on sm and xs, do we have a workaround?

Comment: @KunalTyagi In v5 you can use `sx={{ [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: { px: 0 } }}`. Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/container-disable-gutters-for-xs-and-sm-k9zmwf?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sx` prop to remove the padding in **MUI 5**.

```
  <Container sx={{ px: 0 }}>

  </Container>
```